# How do I get more of my code out of the Enter Button from my GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I currently collect all of the variables from my GUI in the Enter button action. Is there a way for me to get all of this out of my enter button and into another class to clean up the look of it?

```
private void enterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    // saves all entered data to its variable
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

    String dobDay1 = String.valueOf(dobDay.getSelectedItem());
    String dobMonth1 = String.valueOf(dobMonth.getSelectedItem());
    String dobYear1 = String.valueOf(dobYear.getSelectedItem());
    String SdobDay1 = String.valueOf(SdobDay.getSelectedItem());
    String SdobMonth1 = String.valueOf(SdobMonth.getSelectedItem());
    String SdobYear1 = String.valueOf(SdobYear.getSelectedItem());
    String children1 = String.valueOf(children.getSelectedItem());
    String annDay1 = String.valueOf(annDay.getSelectedItem());
    String annMonth1 = String.valueOf(annMonth.getSelectedItem());
    String annYear1 = String.valueOf(annYear.getSelectedItem());
    String state1 = String.valueOf(state.getSelectedItem());
    String dState1 = String.valueOf(dState.getSelectedItem());
    String fName1 = fName.getText();
    String MI1 = MI.getText();
    String lName1 = lName.getText();
    String SfName1 = SfName.getText();
    String SMI1 = SMI.getText();
    String SlName1 = SlName.getText();
    String spouse = SdobMonth1 + "/" + SdobDay1 + "/" + SdobYear1;
    String city1 = city.getText();
    String pMessage0 = pMessage.getText();
    String you = dobMonth1 + "/" + dobDay1 + "/" + dobYear1;
    String ann = annMonth1 + "/" + annDay1 + "/" + annYear1;
    String selfGender = buttonGroup1.getSelection().getActionCommand();
    String spouseGender = buttonGroup2.getSelection().getActionCommand();
    String mType = buttonGroup3.getSelection().getActionCommand();

    Period duration;
    //constructors for birthstones, zodiacs and gender pronouns from respective classes
    birthstone birthstonex = new birthstone(dobMonth1);
    birthstone1 birthstoney = new birthstone1(SdobMonth1);
    zodiac zodiacx = new zodiac(dobMonth1,dobDay1);
    zodiac2 zodiacy = new zodiac2(SdobMonth1, SdobDay1);
    gender gender1 = new gender(selfGender);
    gender2 gender2 = new gender2(spouseGender);
    messageType message = new messageType(mType);
    //String m = String.valueOf(message);
    LocalDate dob = LocalDate.parse(you,dtf);
    LocalDate sdob = LocalDate.parse(spouse,dtf);
    if (dob.compareTo(sdob) > 0) {
        duration = Period.between(sdob, dob);
    }  else {
        duration = Period.between(dob, sdob);
    }

    LocalDate annDate = LocalDate.parse(ann,dtf);
    Period married = Period.between(annDate, today);

    String marriage = String.format("%d year(s), %d month(s), %d day(s) " , married.getYears(), married.getMonths(), married.getDays());
    String difference = String.format("%d year(s), %d month(s), %d day(s) " ,duration.getYears(), duration.getMonths(), duration.getDays());


    output.setText(String.valueOf(messageType.message)+pMessage0);
```

This does work just fine, but it seems like a lot of code in the enter button and wanted to make it cleaner. I am still pretty new to programming and this all started as a serious brute force type program and I have been cleaning it up since. 
I hope there is enough information here to get some help.

Comment: Well, as far as I can see, the only thing the method actually does is generates  an out message of `String.valueOf(messageType.message)+pMessage0`. Message type comes from `buttonGroup3.getSelection().getActionCommand()` and `pMessage0` comes from `pMessage.getText()`, everything else is just nose which does seem to be doing anything

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"everything else is just nose"* Unless you meant 'on the nose' ITYM 'noise'. .. I'm not entirely sure either way. Both are plausible.

Comment: @AndrewThompson On the nose

Comment: @MadProgrammer BTW - are those emoticons from Unicode chars? Let me try:- On the 

Comment: @AndrewThompson 

Comment: It collects all input from the GUI then uses that to generate a message. I have already moved some things into other classes as you can see with the constructors. I am unsure, since I haven't found anything, if I can collect the information and save the variables outside of the button to use later? If so, how?